# I am not able to draw this table in latex

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, multirow

[image]

I have written the following code:

```
\begin{table}
%\centering
\caption{Performance of Mesh Topology.}
\label{tab:meshperformance}
  \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|l||l||l|}
    \hline
    \multirow{2}{*}{Mesh Topology} &
      \multicolumn{2}{c|}{TH(Kbps)} &
      \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Energy(J)} &
      \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Delay(ms)} &
      \multicolumn{2}{c|}{PDR (\%)} \\ \midrule 
      
    & MD/MA,  & MD/MA,  & MD/MA,  & MD/MA, & MD/MA,  & MD/MA,  & MD/MA,  & MD/MA,  \\
    &T=1   & T=5   & T=1   & T=5   & T=1   & T=5   &T=1   &T=5 \\ \midrule 
    With Fusion & 2.1\% & 2.1\% & 2.1\% & 2.1\% & 2.1\% & 2.1\% & 2.1\% & 2.1\% \\
    \hline
    Without Fusion & 11.6\% & 11.6\% & 11.6\% & 11.6\% & 11.6\% & 11.6\% & 2.1\% & 2.1\% \\
    \hline
    %D3 & 5.5\% & 5.5\% & 5.5\% & 5.5\% & 5.5\% & 5.5\% & 2.1\% & 2.1\%  \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

this is what i am getting the output as:[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lines from the `booktabs` package are incompatible with vertical lines, hence the small gaps around the intersections that you observe in your output. If you want to use vertical and horizontal lines, replace the `booktabs` lines with `\hline`. Using `||` in your column specifications will result in a double vertical line. If you want a single vertical lines, use `|` instead. Lastly, the position of your `\multirow` command does not match the image of the expected output. I have alo corrected that in the following MWE.

Since your table is quite wide and therefore unlikely to fit onto the page, I also added a second example with a different layout based on `booktabs` (without vertical lines), `siunitx` for units in teh column headers and improved alignment of numbers in the columns. I also tried to remove repeated information.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
%\centering
\caption{Performance of Mesh Topology.}
\label{tab:meshperformance}
  \begin{tabular}{|p{1.5cm}|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
    \hline
    Mesh Topology &
      \multicolumn{2}{c|}{TH(Kbps)} &
      \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Energy(J)} &
      \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Delay(ms)} &
      \multicolumn{2}{c|}{PDR (\%)} \\ \hline
      
   \multirow[t]{3}{=}{With\newline Fusion} & MD/MA,  & MD/MA,  & MD/MA,  & MD/MA, & MD/MA,  & MD/MA,  & MD/MA,  & MD/MA,  \\
    &T=1   & T=5   & T=1   & T=5   & T=1   & T=5   &T=1   &T=5 \\ \cline{2-9}
     & 2.1\% & 2.1\% & 2.1\% & 2.1\% & 2.1\% & 2.1\% & 2.1\% & 2.1\% \\
    \hline
    Without Fusion & 11.6\% & 11.6\% & 11.6\% & 11.6\% & 11.6\% & 11.6\% & 2.1\% & 2.1\% \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Performance of Mesh Topology.}
\label{tab:meshperformance}
  \begin{tabular}{l*{8}{S[table-format=2.1]}}
    \toprule
    Mesh Topology &
      \multicolumn{2}{c}{TH (Kbps)} &
      \multicolumn{2}{c}{Energy (\si{\joule})} &
      \multicolumn{2}{c}{Delay (\si{\milli\second})} &
      \multicolumn{2}{c}{PDR (\%)} \\
    \cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-5}  \cmidrule(lr){6-7}  \cmidrule(lr){8-9}        
    MD/MA:              & {T=1}  & {T=5}  & {T=1}  & {T=5}  & {T=1}  & {T=5}  & {T=1} & {T=5} \\ 
    With Fusion (\%)    & 2.1    & 2.1    & 2.1    & 2.1    & 2.1    & 2.1    & 2.1   & 2.1 \\
    Without Fusion (\%) & 11.6   & 11.6   & 11.6   & 11.6   & 11.6   & 11.6   & 2.1   & 2.1 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

The excessive width is mostly due to the repeated MD/MA, which can be reduced to one per pair of columns. Also all the % symbols can be avoided by specifying one in the header.

The `\splitcell*` command makes a split cell with no depth; not really needed in this case, but it can come handy in different situations.

You should be able to make this into a caged table, but I can't recommend it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,siunitx,booktabs}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}

\NewDocumentCommand{\splitcell}{sO{t}mm}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
    {\smash[b]{\makesplitcell{#2}{#3}{#4}}}
    {\makesplitcell{#2}{#3}{#4}}%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\makesplitcell}{mmm}{%
  \begin{tabular}[#1]{@{}#2@{}}#3\end{tabular}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\caption{Performance of Mesh Topology.}
\label{tab:meshperformance}

\begin{tabular}{
  @{}
  l
  *{6}{S[table-format=2.1]}
  *{2}{S[table-format=1.1]}
  @{}
}
\toprule
\splitcell*{c}{Mesh \\ Topology} &
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\splitcell{c}{Throughput \\ (Kbps)}} &
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\splitcell{c}{Energy \\ (J)}} &
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\splitcell{c}{Delay \\ (ms)}} &
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\splitcell{c}{PDR \\ (\%)}} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-3}
\cmidrule(lr){4-5}
\cmidrule(lr){6-7}
\cmidrule(l){8-9}
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{MD/MA (\%)}
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{MD/MA (\%)}
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{MD/MA (\%)}
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{MD/MA (\%)} \\
\midrule      
& {$T=1$} & {$T=5$} & {$T=1$} & {$T=5$} & {$T=1$} & {$T=5$} & {$T=1$} & {$T=5$} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-2} \cmidrule(lr){3-3}
\cmidrule(lr){4-4} \cmidrule(lr){5-5}
\cmidrule(lr){6-6} \cmidrule(lr){7-7}
\cmidrule(lr){8-8} \cmidrule(lr){9-9}
With Fusion & 2.1 & 2.1 & 2.1 & 2.1 & 2.1 & 2.1 & 2.1 & 2.1 \\
\addlinespace
Without Fusion & 11.6 & 11.6 & 11.6 & 11.6 & 11.6 & 11.6 & 2.1 & 2.1 \\
\addlinespace
D3 & 5.5 & 5.5 & 5.5 & 5.5 & 5.5 & 5.5 & 2.1 & 2.1  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

By employing `makecell` and `siunitx` packages:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, multirow}
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\mcc{O{1}m}
    {\multicolumn{#1}{c|}{#2}}
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\mcmc{O{1}m}
    {\multicolumn{#1}{c|}{\makecell{#2}}}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
\caption{Performance of Mesh Topology.}
\label{tab:meshperformance}
    \centering
    \setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
    \setcellgapes{3pt}
    \makegapedcells
\begin{tabular}{|r |*{8}{S[table-format=2.1,
                           table-space-text-post={\,\%}]<{\,\%}|}
                }
    \Xhline{1.2pt}
\makecell{Mesh\\ Topology}
    &   \mcc[2]{TH (kbps)} 
            &   \mcc[2]{Energy (\si{\joule})}
                    &   \mcc[2]{TH (kbps)}
                            &   \mcc[2]{PDR (\%)}                   \\
    \Xhline{0.8pt}
MD/MA    
    &   \mcc{$T=1$} 
        &   \mcc{$T=5$}   
            &   \mcc{$T=1$}
                &   \mcc{$T=5$}
                    &   \mcc{$T=1$}
                        &   \mcc{$T=5$}
                            &   \mcc{$T=1$}
                                &   \mcc{$T=5$}                     \\
    \hline
With Fusion
    & 2.1   & 2.1   & 2.1   & 2.1   & 2.1   & 2.1   & 2.1   & 2.1   \cr
    \hline
Without Fusion
    & 11.6  & 11.6  & 11.6  & 11.6  & 11.6  & 11.6  & 2.1   & 2.1   \cr
    \Xhline{1.2pt}
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```